# How do I allow Text to be entered, when using Keypress event in JS

Tags: javascript, forms

Here is my issue:
I have a button to submit a form, but we also want to have the submit happen if the user presses enter as well. I put in the following code and it works, with one exception ... the text box no longer allows entry.

here is the code:

```
$(function () {
    document.getElementById("newsletter-signup-form")
        .addEventListener("keypress", function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                document.getElementById("sign-up-submit").click();
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: Well then check the element the event happen upon initially, and if it is the textarea, don't prevent it ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the `event.preventDefault()` inside the `if`, so you let other keys through.

```
.addEventListener("keypress", function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById("sign-up-submit").click();
    }
});
```